# STL "closest" method?

Tags: c++, search, binary

I'm looking for an STL sort that returns the element "closest" to the target value if the exact value is not present in the container. It needs to be fast, so essentially I'm looking for a slightly modified binary search... I could write it, but it seems like something that should already exist...

Answer (score 9):

Do you mean the `lower_bound`/`upper_bound` functions? These perform a binary search and return the closest element above the value you're looking for.

Clarification: The global versions of lower/upper_bound only work if the range is sorted, as they use some kind of binary search internally. (Obviously, the lower/upper_bound methods in std::map always work). You said in your question that you were looking for some kind of binary search, so I'll assume the range is sorted.

Also, Neither `lower_bound` nor `upper_bound` returns the closest member. If the value `X` you're looking for isn't a member of the range, they will both return the first element greater then `X`. Otherwise, `lower_bound` will return the first value equal to `X`, `upper_bound`will return the last value equals `X`.

So to find the closest value, you'd have to

- call `lower_bound`
- if it returns the end of the range, all values are less then `X`. The last (i.e. the highest) element is the closest one
- it if returns the beginning of the range, all values are greater then `X`. The first (i.e. the lowest) element is the closest one
- if it returns an element in the middle of the range, check that element and the element before - the one that's closer to `X` is the one you're looking for

Comment: These two methods go in the right direction, but they are not *quite* what he asked for. `lower_bound` will return the first element that is larger or equal to the given value, and `upper_bound` returns the last value that is smaller or equal to the given value. These methods do not care if the next value is closer.

Comment: @Philip: dicroce wrote he was looking for a "slightly modified binary search", so I assumed his container is sorted. It's probably good to mention it, though.

Comment: @Space_Cowboy: If the list is sorted, the closest value should either be the last one less or the first one greater than the value he's looking for. Or am I missing something? Could you give an example where that doesn't work?

Comment: @nikie: That means you have to call both functions and see which of the two results is closer. Then it works. Alternatively, you can use a custom predicate like @Philip Potter suggests in his answer.

Comment: @Space: if you have a sorted list, it's best to do 2 O(log n) binary searches rather than one O(n) linear search like mine.

Comment: @Space_Cowboy: I still don't get it. If I have the last element that's lower than the value I'm looking for, then the next element after that should be first element that's greater. Compare the distance and use the closer one. No need to call both functions.

Comment: @nikie: You are right, I didn't think enough. My reason for downvoting you was that you didn't mention any extra steps in your answer, which may suggest to some, that these functions can directly do this. I apologize for not just saying so from the start.

Answer (score 6):

So you're looking for an element which has a minimal distance from some value `k`?

Use `std::transform` to transform each `x` to `x-k`. The use `std::min_element` with a comparison function which returns `abs(l) < abs(r)`. Then add `k` back onto the result.

EDIT: Alternatively, you could just use `std::min_element` with a comparison function `abs(l-k) < abs(r-k)`, and eliminate the `std::transform`.

EDIT2: This is good for unsorted containers. For sorted containers, you probably want nikie's answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the container is already sorted (as implied) you should be able to use `std::upper_bound` and the item directly before to figure out which is closest:

```
// Untested.
template <class Iter, class T>
Iter closest_value(Iter begin, Iter end, T value)
{
    Iter result = std::upper_bound(begin, end, value);
    if(result != begin)
    {
        Iter lower_result = result;
        --lower_result;
        if(result == end || ((value - *lower_result) < (*result - value)))
        {
            result = lower_result;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

If the container is not sorted, use `min_element` with a predicate as already suggested.

Comment: Typo, should be `upper_bound(begin,end,value);`

Comment: What if `upper_bound` returns `end`? Shouldn the function return the last element before `end` then?

Answer (score 2):

If your data is not sorted, use [std::min_element](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/min-element.html) with a comparison functor that calculates your distance.